# Aggregation query with lookup in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using the Spring framework to perform an aggregation on my mongodb. However, the lookup keeps failing and I can't understand why. Here's the query:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("idOfUser").is(loggedInAccount.getId())),
    group("imgID"),
    new CustomAggregationOperation(
        new BasicDBObject("$lookup",
        new BasicDBObject("from","img")
            .append("localField","_id")
            .append("foreignField","_id")
            .append("as","uniqueImgs")
        )
    ),
    limit(pageable.getPageSize()),
    skip(pageable.getPageSize()*pageable.getPageNumber())
);

AggregationResults aggregationResults = mongo.aggregate(aggregation, "comment", String.class); //Using String at the moment just to see the output clearly.
```

`CustomAggregationOperation` is as follows:

```
public class CustomAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomAggregationOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

The Spring MongoDB version of lookup isn't recognised which is why I'm using this `CustomAggregationOperation`. AFAIK it shouldn't affect it.

Ideally what I want to happen is:

1. Get all the comments of the user.
2. Make sure that the imgID is distinct for the comments (so there are only the id's of the imgs that have been commented on)
3. Get the actual img objects related to these ids.
4. Paginate the returned imgs.

At the moment,  step 3 doesn't work, and I think 4 wouldn't work either since limit and skip won't be applied to the objects in "uniqueImgs".
What is returned is:

```
[{ "_id" : "570e2f5cb1b9125510a443f5" , "uniqueImgs" : [ ]}]
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
the imgID stored isn't an ObjectID whereas the _id in the img collection is. Would that have any effect?

Comment: If the two "types" are not the same then the `$lookup` will not be successful, just as it would also fail with any query where you used an incorrect BSON type. So you will need to change the `"imgID"` data to be `ObjectId` values instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, I think another reason why it isn't working is because I've just seen that my version of mongo doesn't support $lookup.

Comment: If it didn't support it then you would have a big "error" as opposed to an empty array. If a pipeline operator is not supported, then that is exactly the error that is thrown. These things are not silent.

Answer (score 6):

The current release (at the time of writing [1.9.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.9.5.RELEASE/reference/html)) has [support](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1326) for the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator and can be [implemented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/LookupOperationUnitTests.java) as (untested):

```
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
    .from("img")
    .localField("_id")
    .foreignField("_id")
    .as("uniqueImgs");

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("idOfUser").is(loggedInAccount.getId())),
    group("imgID"),
    lookupOperation,
    limit(pageable.getPageSize()),
    skip(pageable.getPageSize()*pageable.getPageNumber())
);

AggregationResults aggregationResults = mongo.aggregate(agg, "comment", String.clas);
```

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953464/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-with-other-collection-as-well/61954736?noredirect=1#61954736 ?

Comment: Limit is applied to comment collection, What If I want to limit the results from `img` collection ?