# Spring Data MongoDB - Aggregation with other collection as well

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm working on **Spring Boot v.2.1.3.RELEASE and Spring Data MongoDB**. Due to critical requirement, I had to model like below assuming Employee knows multiple technologies, but primary language would be anyone.

So, I decided to keep technology collection separate and somehow related Employee and technology in the Employee Collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec65750fdcd4e960f4b2f24"),
    "technologyCd" : "AB",
    "technologyName" : "My ABC",
    "ltechnologyNativeName" : "XY",
    "status" : "A"
}
```

So, I've done association like below -

> Note: Multiple Technologies can be associated with one Employee
>
> One Employee can be associated with multiple technologies
>
> Employee can have one and only one Primary Technology

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec507c72d8c2136245d35ce"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    "email" : "j.d@gmail.com",
    .......
    .......
    .......
    "employeeTechnologyRefs" : [ 
        {
            "technologyCd" : "AB",
            "primaryTechnologySw" : "Y",
            "Active" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "technologyCd" : "AB",
            "primaryTechnologySw" : "N",
            "Active" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "technologyCd" : "PR",
            "primaryTechnologySw" : "N",
            "Active" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "technologyCd" : "PR",
            "primaryTechnologySw" : "N",
            "Active" : "A"
        }
    ],
    "countryPhoneCodes" : [ 
        "+352"
    ],
    ....
    ...
}
```

I used below query, how to query over the Technology documents to get the result and map it and create final object?

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.andOperator(
        StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstName) ? Criteria.where("firstName").is(firstName.toUpperCase())
                : Criteria.where(""),
        StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName) ? Criteria.where("lastName").is(lastName.toUpperCase())
                : Criteria.where(""),
        StringUtils.isNotBlank(email) ? Criteria.where("email").is(email.toUpperCase())
                : Criteria.where(""),
        StringUtils.isNotBlank(technologyCd) ? Criteria.where("employeeTechnologyRefs.technologyCd").is(technologyCd.toUpperCase())
                : Criteria.where(""));

MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(criteria);

GroupOperation groupOp = Aggregation
        .group("firstName", "lastName", "email","_id")
        .addToSet("employeeTechnologyRefs").as("employeeTechnologyRefs");

ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("employeeTechnologyRefs");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage, groupOp, projectStage);

AggregationResults<CustomObject> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Employee.class), CustomObject.class);
System.out.println(results);
```

Result should look like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec507c72d8c2136245d35ce"),
    "firstName" : 442,
    "lastName" : "LU",
    "email" : "LUX",
    .......
    .......
    .......
    "employeeTechnologyRefs" : [ 
        {
            "technologyCd" : "AB",
            "technologyName" : "My ABC",
            "ltechnologyNativeName" : "XY",
            "primaryTechnologySw" : "Y",
            "Active" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "technologyCd" : "AB",
            "technologyCd" : "AB",
            "technologyName" : "My ABC",
            "ltechnologyNativeName" : "XY",
            "primaryTechnologySw" : "Y",
            "Active" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "technologyCd" : "PR",
            "technologyCd" : "AB",
            "technologyName" : "My ABC",
            "ltechnologyNativeName" : "XY",
            "primaryTechnologySw" : "Y",
            "Active" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "technologyCd" : "PR",
            "technologyCd" : "AB",
            "technologyName" : "My ABC",
            "ltechnologyNativeName" : "XY",
            "primaryTechnologySw" : "Y",
            "Active" : "A"
        }
    ],
    ....
    
}
```

Comment: How do you want your final result should look like? If you want to join the result you can use $lookup stage to match the data in other collection https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#unwind-example

Comment: @DeepakSingh - I've updated result, could you please help me to modify query ?

Comment: How is Employee and Technology collection are linked? on which property? can you please share that? I think you can use lookup stage here.

Comment: They should be linked on  "technologyCd"  as  in Technology collection its a unique field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use below lookup operation in your code, you should able to get the answer as expected, and you don't need group operation in your code.

Edited Answer: This is how whole code should look like. One more thing, you don't need projection and if you need try projecting specific field only, and as part of the lookup operation do not use the same field as it is in your collection, otherwise it will override existing data from employee collection.

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.andOperator(
            StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstName) ? Criteria.where("firstName").is(firstName.toUpperCase())
                    : Criteria.where(""),
            StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName) ? Criteria.where("lastName").is(lastName.toUpperCase())
                    : Criteria.where(""),
            StringUtils.isNotBlank(email) ? Criteria.where("email").is(email.toUpperCase())
                    : Criteria.where(""),
            StringUtils.isNotBlank(technologyCd) ? Criteria.where("employeeTechnologyRefs.technologyCd").is(technologyCd.toUpperCase())
                    : Criteria.where(""));

    MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(criteria);

    /*GroupOperation groupOp = Aggregation
            .group("firstName", "lastName", "email","_id")
            .addToSet("employeeTechnologyRefs").as("employeeTechnologyRefs");
            */

    LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().
                                     from("technology_collection_name").
                                     localField("employeeTechnologyRefs.technologyCd").
                                     foreignField("technologyCd").
                                     as("employeeTechnologyRefsOtherName");

   /* ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("employeeTechnologyRefs");
  */  
// And if you want to project specific field from employee array you can use something like.
ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("employeeTechnologyRefs.fieldName")
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage, lookupOperation, projectStage);

    AggregationResults<CustomObject> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Employee.class), CustomObject.class);
    System.out.println(results);
```

Comment: will try... does it returns all operations where technologyCd matches ? At this moment I am really struggling to map the `CustomObject`

Comment: Could you please show how to use this with the Aggregation as I shown below ?

Comment: Can you please share exact data (i.e. how does your Employee collection look like and Technology Collection look like).

Comment: Hey I've already shared that above, first json document is of Technology and other json document is of Employee. What else do u need ?

Comment: updated the answer, this is how it should be, please check your CustomObject is matching with your result structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214422/discussion-between-ash-p-and-deepak-singh).